# What's the difference between sudo su - and sudo su --

Tags: sudo, su

When I am working on our RHEL machines, I use `sudo su -` to switch to being root. One day, a typo meant I typed `sudo su --` instead - it seems to me that everything was the same as with a single hyphen, except that I was in the same folder as before I issued the command (with a single hyphen I find myself in `/root`).

Are there other differences? Is it safe to use this in scenarios where I know I want to work in the same directory?

Answer (score 27):

When you provide a double-hyphen the experience you will have is identical to if you had just executed `sudo su` without any hyphen.

Passing a single hyphen is identical to passing `-l` or `--login`.  The man page for `su` describes the behavior as:

> Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.

This includes setting your directory to your home directory and setting a bunch of other environment variables.

Passing a double-hyphen to a command is typically used to mark the end of command-line flags and the beginning of non-flag arguments.  For example, if you run `touch -R` you'll receive an error saying that -R is not an option to `touch`, but if you run `touch -- -R` it will create a file named `-R`.  This is true of many command-line tools (`ls -R` will do a recursive `ls` whereas `ls -- -R` will perform an `ls` on a file or directory named `-R`.

So, to wrap this up, when you pass *only* `--` to `su` it is basically ignoring the `--` and acting like you did not pass any option at all.

Comment: I will create a question from it but `sudo su -` and `sudo su -l` differs. On an account where I ssh into with a key only, and I have sudo rights to change to a specific other user, `sudo su -` changes the user without problems but `sudo su -l` or `sudo su --login` will ask for a sudo password, which I don't have (although by examining `sudo -l` I could execute `/bin/su` with NOPASSWD)

Comment: @karatedog, it looks like you didn't create a question....

Comment: @karatedog I'm a bit late to the party here, but I'd *really* like to see that question and any answers that come in. I'm wondering about this myself due to some ambiguous and/or confusing text in the `su` man page.

Comment: Oh, this was 5 years ago! If you have more up-to-date, reproducible example with a fresh operating system, please go ahead and create that question.